# ¿Como puedo mostrar dos arrays en un mismo fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment

Estoy intentando hacer un `Array` con diferentes categorías para mostrarlas en un mismo `fragment`, el problema es que solo me muestra un `Array` y no los dos. Quisiera saber si se puede hacer así o hay otra manera.

Este es mi código en donde quiero meter los dos `Array`:

```
public class FragmentNovedades extends Fragment  {

public RecyclerView recyclerView;
public LinearLayoutManager linearLayout;

public FragmentNovedades() {    }


  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_novedades, container, false);
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
linearLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayout);

ListaAdaptador adapter = new ListaAdaptador(getContext(),ListaObjetos.getCourses());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

 //esta es la segunda lista que quiero meter pero solo me muestra la de 
 arriba

 ListaAdaptadorVideo adaptervideo=new 
 ListaAdaptadorVideo(getContext(),ListaObjetosVideo.getVideos());
 recyclerView.setAdapter(adaptervideo);

  return view;

 } 
  }
```

Cuando pongo las siguientes dos líneas no me muestra ambas listas (sólo una), cómo puedo hacer para mostrar las dos?:

```
ListaAdaptador adapter = new ListaAdaptador(getContext(), 
ListaObjetos.getCourses());
ListaAdaptadorVideo adaptervideo=new ListaAdaptadorVideo(getContext(), 
ListaObjetosVideo.getVideos());
```

Comment: Qué error muestra la consola?

Comment: @Carmen No muestra ningún error el problema es que solo me muestra la lista de"ListaAdaptador" y la de "ListaAdaptadorVideo" no la muestra y si comento la primer "ListaAdaptador" ya me deja ver la de Video.

Comment: Te estoy poniendo una respuesta, enseguida la tienes

Comment: Muchas gracias @Carmen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tienes un único `recyclerView`, y a este elemento intentas setearle 2 adaptadores diferentes. Ten en cuenta que instancias un único recyclerView.

```
...public RecyclerView recyclerView, recyclerViewVideo;...
```

Y luego los asocias al mismo elemento de la vista cuando deberías tener 2:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerViewVideo = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_video);
```

Y luego instancias cada adaptador en el correspondiente.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: y como podría meter dos recycler view en una mismo layout?

Comment: Creas 2 elementos RecyclerView con distinto nombre. Sólo va a darte problemas de formato si ambos hacen scroll.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que Carlos